# Does it some mistakes in reading a file?

Tags: python

Define a function longest_lines that takes in a filename and returns all of the lines in that file of that length.

Here is my code.

```
# define longest_lines
def longest_lines(file_name):
    content1 = open(file_name, "r").read()
    l1 = content1.strip().split("\n")
    max_number = max(map(int, map(len, l1)))
    def longest_char(char1):
        if len(char1) == int(max_number):
            return char1
    l2 = list(filter(longest_char, l1))
    return print(l2)
```

I creat a words100.txt. But when I run a file, it is always wrong.

```
>>> longest_lines(words100.txt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'words100' is not defined
>>> longest_lines(words100)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'words100' is not defined
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Exu.png)

Comment: Hi, you need to pass the path to the file as a string.
'filename.txt' or in this case 'words100.txt'

Comment: Do not add links to images, it's not easy to follow them and do not help to answer your question

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes -

```
longest_lines('words100.txt')
```

Or double quotes-

```
longest_lines("words100.txt")
```

Basically, it should be like a string. Then, you can pass it into the function.

Also, this line at the end of the function definition -  `return print(l2)` should just be `return l2`